# Convert PyTorch Trained Model To Core ML model

Tags: python, visual-studio, pytorch

I'm a newbie in python. I have model.ckpt file. I want to convert that model to core ML model .mlmodel to using in iOS project. I have spent a lots of time to research but I don't know how to do it. Someone told me use coremltools but I could not find tutorial how to do that. This code bellow is not work.

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('./model.ckpt',
                                                input_names='image',
                                                image_input_names='image',
                                                output_names='output',
                                                class_labels=['1', '2'],
                                                image_scale=1/255)
coreml_model.save('abc.mlmodel')
```

Comment: Does [this](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/pytorch-conversion) help?

Comment: @Salahuddin thank but I don't know how to load model .ckpt from folder.

Comment: Pan try this [blog](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) for saving and loading models.

Comment: @Salahuddin thank, But this conversation require .pt or .pth, how can I convert .ckpt to .pt or pth

Comment: I didn't notice before that your model is not a PyTorch model it is a TensorFlow model, right? if so then try [this](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml)

Comment: This [medium](https://medium.com/@jianshi_94445/convert-a-tensorflow-model-to-coreml-model-using-tfcoreml-8ce157f1bc3b) article might be helpful as well

Comment: @Salahuddin thank but I don't understand this article. I don't see load .ckpt file . Could you help me with code?

Comment: Do you have the model architecture and can you load it? if so, then [this](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/tensorflow-2#convert-a-pre-trained-model) should help

Comment: From what I can tell, you will have to load weights into model architecture first and then convert that model

Answer (score 0):

From the [article](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/tensorflow-2#convert-a-pre-trained-model):

> convert_tf_keras_model

```
# Tested with TensorFlow 2.6.2
import tensorflow as tf
import coremltools as ct

tf_keras_model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
    ]
)

# Pass in `tf.keras.Model` to the Unified Conversion API
mlmodel = ct.convert(tf_keras_model, convert_to="mlprogram")

# or save the keras model in SavedModel directory format and then convert
tf_keras_model.save('tf_keras_model')
mlmodel = ct.convert('tf_keras_model', convert_to="mlprogram")

# or load the model from a SavedModel and then convert
tf_keras_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('tf_keras_model')
mlmodel = ct.convert(tf_keras_model, convert_to="mlprogram")

# or save the keras model in HDF5 format and then convert
tf_keras_model.save('tf_keras_model.h5')
mlmodel = ct.convert('tf_keras_model.h5', convert_to="mlprogram")
```

To load tensorflow saved models, check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load)

Comment: I don't understand. I have mode.ckpt file. Please guide me step be step.

Comment: First load the model in your architecture using `model = YoruModelClass())` and the load weights using  `model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)`. Checkpoint path should contain these files  `['cp.ckpt.index', 'cp.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001', 'checkpoint']`

Comment: I have only .ckpt file, can I do that?

Comment: Then there is a problem. Did you train the model yourself?

Comment: No, I downloaded it from GitHub.

Comment: please check on that repo for other files as well

Comment: No other file in model folder

Comment: Could you train the model yourself

Comment: I can't. I just want to use that trained-model for iOS

Comment: https://github.com/saic-mdal/lama could you help me how to use this lib in iOS?

Comment: They have provided PyTorch  [weights](https://github.com/saic-mdal/lama/tree/main/models/lpips_models), you can use PyTorch API of coremltools

Comment: there are 3 models. What's model can I pick?

Comment: I think they aren't trained models

Comment: Why not just give them a inference test run